# Unable to connect to smtp remote server

Tags: c#, smtp

I am unable to connect to a remote SMTP server. The firewall is not blocking ports 587 and 25. I have tried to used telnet but it is not  working.

```
try {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress from = new 
                   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test04@outlook.com");
                                System.Net.Mail.MailAddress to = new 
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@gmail.com");
                                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);
                                message.IsBodyHtml = false;
                                message.Subject = "Hello";
                                message.Body = "My Name is Simple Blog";
                                using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new 
                      System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com",587))
                                {
                                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                                    client.Credentials =new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                                     client.EnableSsl = true;
                                    client.Send(message);
                                   
                                    Console.WriteLine("Sent");
                                }
                            }
                            catch(SmtpException ex)
                            {
                                if(ex.InnerException !=null)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                                }  
                            }
```

Error:

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.98.16.226:587
                       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
                       at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
                       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                       at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
                       at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
                       at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
                       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
                       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
                       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
                       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
                       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to that mail server from the same machine but using an e-mail client?

Comment: Are you inside a corporate network?  Does code work from your home pc.  You cannot get to gmail from inside a corporate network.  There firewall is using port forwarding for  ports 25 and 587 to an internal proxy server that is used for outlook.

Comment: It was working fine before.. I don’t why the error came up

Comment: it was showing the same error while connecting to another mail server.. like smtp.gmail.com

Comment: @jdweng `You cannot get to gmail from inside a corporate network`...that depends on how the corporate network is configured. But yes, point taken that in _most_ companies _most_ users would find it would be disallowed by either firewall, or proxy, or both. I dislike the sweeping generalisation though. Also OP is connecting to O365 not gmail (although they later stated gmail was also a problem (unsurprisingly)).

Comment: `working fine before` ...before what? Identify the change which occurred, and then you might have a chance of solving the issue. But the simple meaning of the error message is that your code cannot even connect to that server, never mind attempt to send the email. `The firewall is not blocking ports 587 and 25`...well, _something_ is blocking it. You need to find out what that is. We can't really help you since we know nothing about your network configuration, and you didn't answer Llama or jdweng's questions.

Comment: Usually inside a corporate network you have to use default credentials and not username/password [new NetworkCredential("username", "password")].  The default credentials come from the user mail settings on machine which normally get update the first time a user logs into outlook from a PC.  I'm not sure exactly how that is done in O365.

Comment: @ADyson.... I mean the codes are working fine before. I started gotten error all of a sudden.

Comment: @jdweng.... I don’t use cooperate network....

Comment: I’m only using wifi connection for it... I don’t know maybe I made some configurations out of ignorance

Comment: How will I discover what is blocking 25 and 587 ports

Comment: `are working fine before`...yes, but before **what**? What event occurred around the time it suddenly stopped working? Did you change the code? Or change the operating environment? Did someone else make a change. If it previously worked, then something must have happened.

Comment: `How will I discover`...check router settings, check local firewall settings for outbound rules, check if apps are blocked etc. It's probably something you can research online already, about what techniques and tools you can use to look into network issues. To broad for the comments section here.

Comment: O365 may still need a default Network Credential.  Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to send out an email from some Outlook.com account, using your C# program.

To send out email with smtp from outlook, you really have to make sure to follow [this manual](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040). It talks about that smtp is disabled by default, and you have to enable it for your account.

Also if you have configured MFA (so a token or a text) you’re out off luck, since it won’t accept your password. Of that is the case you should create a special “app password” as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944).

You code looks fine, and as long as you have followed these guides (correct host and ports). You should be fine.

I would recommend using a special smtp provider for applications though. For example sendgrid, they have a decent “free” plan if you don’t send many mails.